# Why can't I load a sqlalchemy result into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a list of data containing 3-tuples from a sqlalchemy query that look like this:

```
data = [('Fast Company', 'Finance', Decimal('225')), ('Fast Company', 'George W. Bush', Decimal('0')), ('Buzzfeed', 'Facebook', Decimal('747')), ('Ars Technica', 'Childcare', Decimal('244')), ('Fast Company', 'Elon Musk', Decimal('19201')), ('Fast Company', 'United States', Decimal('1718')), ('Fast Company', 'New York City', Decimal('286')), ('Fast Company', 'Google', Decimal('20283')), ('Fast Company', 'Twitter', Decimal('0')), ('Fast Company', 'Nutrition', Decimal('70590'))]
```

Notice that the third element in each tuple is a [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) object. If I try to load this data into a pandas dataframe like so:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

I get this error:

`AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns`

Yet if I simply convert the list into a numpy array first:

```
data = np.array(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Everything works as expected. Why?

Or, alternatively, if I just convert my data so that the Decimal-objects are normal floats, everything also works as expected.

Why can't I load a tuple containing a decimal type into a dataframe?

**EDIT**
Apparently (thank you @BrenBarn), my problem is not due to a decimal object in the tuple, but instead due to the fact that each tuple in my list is not in fact a tuple. They are actually some kind of sqlalchemy collections objects:

```
(Pdb) type(data[0])
<class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.result'>
```

What is it about these special "tuples" that is keeping me from using them as I desire?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  `pandas.DataFrame(data)` works fine for me  with your `data`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @BrenBarn for pointing this out. It appears that the data I listed in my question also works for me too, if I copy & paste it from the question. But actually this data is returned from a sqlalchemy query, and each tuple is not actually a tuple (see my edit on the question.)

Comment: If you don't have Decimal objects in your SQLAlchemy data, does it then work?  I don't know enough about SQLAlchemy to know what those result objects are, but if converting them to lists or numpy arrays works, you should probably just do that.  I also see [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/garaud/bda10fa55df5723e27da) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/Ss3Ewj0pitw) that look relevant.

Comment: Yes, without decimal objects, it works. And, yeah, coverting to numpy array works too, so I am just doing that to move forward with my project (my question is purely for education), but I can't figure out why this strange tuple-like sqlalchemy object can't be use directly. Thanks for the links. They do look relevant; I'll see if they can lead me to an answer.

Comment: What database do you use? What type does column have?